# will the inout parameter change if they are modified from outside the function? (swift)

Tags: ios, swift3

I am writing a download image method for UIImageView.

```
extension UIImageView {
func downloadAndSetImage( inout url: String) {
    customDownloadLibrary(url: String?, completion{ image: UIImage, downloadedURL: String?, error: String in 
         if url == downloadedURL {
             self.image = image
         }
    })
}
```

will this code fix the issue caused when image is applied to wrong UIImageView when the url is changed?

EDIT
Here is the full scenario. UIImageView is used in a UITableViewCell.

```
class CustomCell : UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var weak cellImage: UIImage!
    var cellUrl = "someurl"
    func setupcell(url: String) {
        self.cellUrl = url
        downloadAndSetImage(url: self.cellUrl)
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        self.cellUrl = ""
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not modifying the `url`, what's the needs for `inout`?

Comment: @Tj3n I have updated the issue. Thanks.